# Paraview: Can I annotate sources via python scripts?

Tags: python, paraview

I am visualizing a 3D dataset in paraview and want to annotate certain surface locations by marking them with an object (e.g. cone) and annotating them with text. I want to do this via python script.

Putting the cones is not a problem. But the sources *Text* and *a3DText* do not have property for location.

Does anybody know a way how I could do this?

Answer:

After generating the 3D Text source, you can put it into view using *Show*, then the position property can be changed:

```
renderView1 = GetActiveViewOrCreate('RenderView')
text = a3DText()
textDisplay = Show(text, renderView1)
textDisplay.Position = [1,1,0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a method that exploits the representation properties (so, if you change visalization, you have to do it again)

Here is what I tried in the paraview gui (4.1):

- Tools - Start trace
- Source - 3D text
- make sure you are visualizing it
- in the 3dtext property panel, go to advanced options (the gear symbol)
- in the visualization properties there is a field "translation", you can modify that value
- I also modified the scale because it was too big for my object
- Tools -stop trace : you can see the corresponding python instructions

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful. I will edit my question with what i found out using your advice